# Scenekit SCNRenderer snapshot orientation issue

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, metal

SCNRenderer.snapshot works good in portrait mode.

If the device is in landscape the ARSCNView is viewed correctly in device, but on taking snapshot there is a mismatch between camera preview and 3d model orientation.

**renderer.snapshot in portrait**

[image: portrait]

**renderer.snapshot in landscape**

[image: landscape]

**Actual screenshot of device in landscape mode** (expected result of renderer.snapshot in landscape)

[image: screenshot]

[Video recording for better understanding the issue](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yvSAo8MXHjAYFI-M8JvF8dX2FgXDTGY-/view?usp=sharing)

Apple developer forum mentioning same issue [link 1](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/106009),
[link 2](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/110872)

To simulate issue in XCode File -> New -> Project -> Augmented Reality App
and add the below code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        .
        .
        .
        if let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice(){
        self.renderer = SCNRenderer(device: device, options: nil)
        renderer.scene = self.sceneView.scene
    }
}

@IBAction func captureButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let time = CACurrentMediaTime()
    let img = renderer.snapshot(atTime: time, with: CGSize(width: self.sceneView.frame.width, height: self.sceneView.frame.height), antialiasingMode: .none)
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self, #selector(imageSaved(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. What is the difference between the two landscape images? Is it displaying correctly to the screen but not correctly with the snapshot render?

Comment: @JeshuaLacock Sorry for the late reply, screenshot of device is what actually see in iphone. The other landscape image is renderer.snapshot taken holding device in same orientation. But camera preview is rotated in the saved png file.

Comment: I added a video recording to question showing how the landscape image is generated